# Http connections in jar slower than in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, http, jar

I have a java software that I made on Eclipse and during the execution there is a series of http requests and responses that I have to make. They run pretty smoothly on Eclipse (using the org.apache.http library) but, when I export to a runnable jar, it's painful to see the time it takes between each http connection. I can almost say that the execution takes roughly 10x longer. I'm on the same JRE and I'm using the same parameters I use to open eclipse ( -Xms40m -Xmx512m).

JVM console shows that Eclipse spawns 5 threads to handle my program. The runnable jar uses 9 daemon and 1 user thread.

Can anyone help me figure out the issue here?

Thank you.

Comment: So is the jar faster, or not? You title and your content says otherwise

Comment: Jar is slower... How do i edit the title?

Comment: Title fixed. Jar is slower.

Comment: Is your JAR signed somehow?

Comment: Nope. Jar is not signed.

Answer (score 0):

Diagnose the network latency. Trying pinging the host you are trying to connect from the machine that has eclipse running, and the machine that you are running from the jar.

Comment: It's the same machine with the same network conditions connecting to the same websites. Even the "non-http" part of the program seems to run slower (albeit not by much).